# Terraform bucket_notification throwing an error

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

So I followed this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_notification.html) to create a lambda function that is triggered by an s3 event in tf. When I run apply I get keep getting the following error:

```
module.elb_logs_to_es.aws_s3_bucket_notification.elb_logs_bucket: 1 error(s) occurred:

aws_s3_bucket_notification.elb_logs_bucket: Error putting S3 notification configuration: AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Here's my configuration:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "elb_logs_to_es" {


function_name = "send-elb-logs-to-es"
  s3_bucket     = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  s3_key        = "elb_logs_to_es/elb_to_es.zip"
  handler       = "elb_to_es.lambda_handler"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.elb_logs_role.arn}"
  runtime       = "python3.6"

}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "elb_logs_bucket" {
  bucket = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.elb_logs_to_es.arn}"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "elb_bucket_access" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.elb_logs_to_es.arn}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "elb_logs_role" {

  name = "elb_logs_sending_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

I also tried changing bucket policy manually to allow the role to PutObject in it but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: What IAM permissions does the user/role that is executing Terraform have?

Comment: That was it, I have a role that is assumed in provider file but was trying to use the role used by lambda function itself. Thank you.

Comment: I've voted to close this as something not reproducible because unfortunately it's not going to be something that would be useful for anyone else who comes across this. In general with AWS if you get an Access Denied issue it's going to be an IAM issue.